# Why is the SMSbuilder plugin unsupported by phoneGap Build?

Tags: plugins, cordova, build, sms

I just tried to upload a test app on PhoneGap Build, which contains the plugin SMS Builder, which is included in the supported plugins list on the PhoneGap Build website. I added it to the config file like so - 
   
But when I try to build it, it gives me **"plugin unsupported: com.arnia.plugins.smsbuilder"**

Why does PhoneGap Build shows it is unsupported, if it's in the list of supported plugins?